# Drupal 7 module JW Player have wrong height when displaying youtube embed video on iPad Safari

Tags: ipad, drupal-7, mobile-safari, jwplayer

I have Drupal 7 with JW Player module version 7.x-1.0-alpha1 installed on it. The YouTube embed video are displaying properly except on the latest iPad Safari.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1cZK0Rp : you'll find the embeded youtube down the page.

Comment: This is an issue with iOS 7. We are going to fix this for 6.8. However, in the mean time, you can use this patch to fix this - http://powered-by-haiku.co.uk/?p=563

Comment: Many Thanks Ethan. I'll get back to you if there's an issue.

Comment: No problem, any time.